# Magento terrible domain error

Tags: magento

I just Resolve Domain Names in my centos 6.0 server. Everything is right but!!

When I visit a product page, for example www.example.com/productname.html, everything is ok. But when i visit the same page without "www", for example example.com/productname.html. It will be redirect to the index page.

What happened? Thanks in advance!

Comment: +1 i got same issue in WordPress site.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your .htaccess does not rewrite all your urls to index page

Comment: would you like to tell me how to edit .htaccess file? I really

Comment: dude no one's gonna work here for you for free, ask a proper question and you get help